# How to enable logging in Apache Ace?

Tags: apache, logging, apache-ace

Is it possible to enable logging in Apache Ace? If yes, How?
In the source code, i can see that the LogService is used to write messages to the log. But i am not able to locate the logs when i start the ace devserver.

Answer (score 0):

The LogService is a standard compendium service, and you can use any implementation to actually record the log statements. We use the one from Apache Felix, and there are shell commands to actually retrieve log statements (hint, the command is called "log"). This implementation does not write them to disk though. Based on the specification, it would be easy to do this yourself though. A LogReader exists to read from, and you can register yourself as a LogListener.